# What's the difference between aqueous NaOH and dilute NaOH?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, concentration

> Dilute $\ce{NaOH}$ can be prepared by adding a suitable amount of concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$.

What's the difference between "dilute $\ce{NaOH}$" and "aqueous $\ce{NaOH}$"?

Answer (score 6):

*Dilute* simply means that the concentration of the solute of interest, in this case $\ce{NaOH}$, is low relative to some reference.  One could imagine a non-aqueous, dilute solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ in, say, methanol.

An *aqueous* solution is one where the solvent is water, regardless of the concentration of the dissolved solute(s).

So, for example, the following combinations of the terms are possible:

- **Concentrated aqueous solution** - High $\ce{NaOH}$ concentration in a water solvent
- **Dilute aqueous solution** - Low $\ce{NaOH}$ concentration in a water solvent
- **Concentrated methanolic solution** - High $\ce{NaOH}$ concentration in a methanol solvent
- **Dilute methanolic solution** - Low $\ce{NaOH}$ concentration in a methanol solvent